# How can I use Wordpress functions outside of the Wordpress folder?

Tags: wordpress

I have a folder called "form" that is seperate from the our WordPress directory.

public_html/wordpress 
public_html/form

How can the directory "form" use the wordpress functions (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference) from the "wordpress" folder? Do I have to Include some file?

Thanks!

Comment: Check out functions.php. Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained

Answer (score 0):

You have to include wp-blog-header.php. But it's better to use wordpress plugin to achieve it.